# Tem como fazer um código CSS para um navegador especifico?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Seguinte, estou montando uma página que em determinado local eu uso um `max-height`, propriedade essa que não funciona no IE11.

```
img {
    max-height: 45px;
}
```

Para solucionar isso no IE em especifico eu posso trocar o `max-height` por `height: 45px`, mas é possível fazer isso só para o IE? pois precisava desse `max-height` nos outros navegadores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso do IE versões 10 e 11, é possível utilizar uma media query:

```css
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

<sub>Fonte: [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419263)</sub>

Para os demais navegadores (modernos), recomenda-se não testar qual é o navegador, e sim se ele suporta a propriedade que você pretende usar, por meio do [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports).

Comment: Resolveu perfeitamente, obrigado. (: